# Add Outlook signature to new Mail item

Tags: excel, vba

I create a new email from the 2 cells outlined in the code. The new email doesn't have my email signature attached to it.

I have tried to work it out but I'm struggling a little bit. Does it pull it from the `HTMLBody` reference?

```
Sub SendHTMLEmail(from_sender As String, what_address1 As String, cc_sender As String, subject_line1 As String, mail_body1 As String)

      Dim olapp As Outlook.Application
      Dim olmail As Outlook.MailItem

      Set olapp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
      Set olmail = olapp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

      olmail.SentOnBehalfOfName = from_sender
      olmail.To = what_address1
      olmail.CC = cc_sender
      olmail.Subject = subject_line1
      olmail.HTMLBody = mail_body1
      olmail.Display

End Sub

Sub SendHoldingEmail()

      Dim EmailWordings As Excel.Worksheet
      Dim row_number As Long
      Dim from_sender As String, cc_sender As String, Email_Subject As String, full_name As String, mail_body_message As String


      Set EmailWordings = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("EmailWordings")

      row_number = 1

      Do
         DoEvents

         row_number = row_number + 1

         from_sender = "blah@hotmail.com"
         cc_sender = "blah@hotmail.com"
         mail_body_message = EmailWordings.Range("D3")
         Email_Subject = EmailWordings.Range("B3")

         Call SendHTMLEmail(from_sender, "", cc_sender, Email_Subject, mail_body_message)

      Loop Until row_number = 2


  End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set the HTMLbody, make sure to append the existing HTMLbody to the end of it.  That contains the existing signature.

```
Sub SendEmail()

    Dim OutlookApplication As Object, OutlookMail As Object

    Set OutlookApplication = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutlookMail = OutlookApplication.CreateItem(0)
    With OutlookMail
        .GetInspector
        .HTMLBody = "Email Content" & .HTMLBody
        .Display
    End With

End Sub
```